# Parsing json from incoming datastream to perform simple transformations in Flink

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, data-stream

I am using Apache Flink with AWS Kineses for the first time. Basically my objective is to transform incoming data from a Kinesis stream in such a way that I can perform simple transformations such as filtering and aggregating.

I am adding the source using the below:

```
return env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(inputStreamName, new SimpleStringSchema(), inputProperties));
```

Eventually when I am print the incoming stream I am getting json data in as expected:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<String> input = createSourceFromStaticConfig(env);
input.print();
```

This is a sample result of the print:

> {"event_num": "5530", "timestmap": "2019-03-04 14:29:44.882376",
>   "amount": "80.4", "type": "Purchase"} {"event_num": "5531", "timestmap": "2019-03-04
>   14:29:44.881379", "amount": "11.98", "type": "Service"}

Can someone enlighten me how I can access these json elements in such a way that I can perform simple transformation such as, selecting only records containing "Service" as a type?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `SimpleStringSchema` the resulting stream of events is of type `String`. Therefore you would need to parse the string first and then you could apply filters etc.

You may want to have a look though at [JsonNodeDeserializationSchema](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/connectors/kafka.html#the-deserializationschema), which will produce `ObjectNode`.